# How to extract a item from compose powerautomate

Tags: power-automate

How to extract a item from compose.
For example I have a compose item like below,
How to get **"AAAA"** only and input create a item to sharepoint List.

I tyied
`outputs('Select')?['Title']`

Appear Error msg like that  "Array elements can only be selected using an integer index."

```
Compose 
{ "Titile" : "AAAA",
  "TitleB" : "BBBB",
  "TitleC" : "CCCC",
  "TitleD" * "DDDD}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your JSON is far from being valid so I've made some assumptions and have included it here with what I used for my answer ...

```
{ 
  "TitleA": "AAAA",
  "TitleB": "BBBB",
  "TitleC": "CCCC",
  "TitleD": "DDDD"
}
```

My suggestion is that you use variables instead of compose.

Here is my flow ...

[image: Flow]

With the second step, this is the expression I used ...

```
variables('Json Object')?['TitleA']
```

This is the end result ...

[image: TitleA]

Comment: Thank you for kindly suggestion. I change to make a compose one by one. Resolve this issue. thanks.